# How to tell if you're currently in the last row of an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a keydown event that I'm using to add a blank row to a table.
But I only want the new row to be added if the keydown event happens when the cursor is in last row of the table.

This is my current jQuery event.
.glCreditValue is the class of an input textbox that resides in the last TD of the table row.
So when the user tabs out of that input, IF the TD that the input is inside of is in the last row of the table, I want to add a new row.

Being that the table data is generated dynamically, every row's final TD has an input textbox with the class .glCreditValue.

```
$(".glCreditValue").keydown(function(event) {
        var keycode = event.keyCode;
        if (keycode == 9) {
            //HERE i would like to make sure that i'm in the last row of the table
            AddNewRow();
        }
    });
```

I'm trying to make use of the tr:last selector, but I'm not sure quite where to go from here.

Comment: Do you want to handle clicks on the whole last row, or just the last column of the last row?

Comment: Just the last column, which is why I'm specifying only that .glCreditValue keydown.
Only the input textboxes in the final TDs of each row have that class assigned to them.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, for example you could check the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) parent `<tr>` and see if it [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) a [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), like this:

```
$(".glCreditValue").keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 9 && $(this).closest("tr").is(":last-child")) {
      AddNewRow();
  }
});
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! I'll 'accept' that as my answer in about 6 minutes when it lets me, haha.

Comment: @Nick Hate to dredge up an older question, but would it be useful/advisable to add a check for the shift-key to the conditional? That would prevent a "tab-left" from triggering the conditional, no? Awesome answer, regardless... :]

Comment: @Tieson - Sure, just depends what UI behavior you're after.  If you want to prevent a shift from doing it then just add a `!event.shiftKey && ` to the start of that `if` check.  From a UI perspective though, I'd expect the shift version to *undo* the new row (if it were empty only?), so that'd be some additional code you'd want in IMO.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it without having the overhead of running a selector is to simply get [the `.closest()` row](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), then go to [the `.next()` element](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and test [its `.length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length/).

It will be `0` if you were on the last `<tr>`.

```
if( !$(this).closest('tr').next().length ) {
   // was the last row
}
```